# How is Turkmenistan exporting gas to Azerbaijan?

Tags: trade, gas, azerbaijan, turkmenistan

[According](https://turkmenportal.com/en/blog/58359/azerbaijan-imported-more-than-857-million-cubic-meters-of-gas-from-turkmenistan-for-110-million-usd-in2022) to the "Turkmen Portal", Turkmenistan was the main gas exporter to Azerbaijan in 2022:

> Declared gas imports to Azerbaijan in 2022 amounted to 1 billion 16 million 423,6 thousand cubic meters, which is 2 times higher than in 2021, imports from Turkmenistan amounted to more than 857 million cubic meters worth more than 110 million USD, reports “Interfax-Azerbaijan”. [...] In the structure of gas imports to Azerbaijan in the reporting period, 84,3% [is] accounted for supplies from Turkmenistan [...]

I'm reading however that the [Trans-Caspian Gas Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Caspian_Gas_Pipeline)
 which would directly connect these two countries is a pipe dream due to opposition from Russia and Iran. So, how is Turkmenistan exporting gas to Azerbaijan presently? I'm guessing it's routed through some other countrie(s), but which?

Answer (score 6):

If you finish reading the article you quoted from, it literally explains this:

> As previously reported, since January 2022, Iran has begun transporting gas received from Turkmenistan to Azerbaijan in accordance with a trilateral swap agreement. In general, the agreement provides for the supply to Azerbaijan through Iran of up to 1,5-2 billion cubic meters of Turkmen gas per year.
>
> In early June 2022, Azerbaijani Economy Minister Mikayil Jabbarov and Iranian Oil Minister Javad Ouji signed a Memorandum of Understanding in Baku, according to which gas supplies from Turkmenistan to Azerbaijan through Iran will double.

Basically Turkmenistan exports gas to Iran, and Iran sends an equivalent amount to Azerbaijan.